# App not compatible with buildpack

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-cli

Hello I am trying to deploy my app to heroku, but I keep getting `App not compatible with buildpack`

I have found different answers stating that I have to set python version in my Pipfile. But I have already done that:

```
[[source]]
url = ""
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
dj-database-url = "*"
django = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
whitenoise = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

So I am kind of clueless as to how I can fix this. And I have set the buildpack with `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python` So what to do ?